# whole listview items not capturing while taking the screenshot

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android full layout not capturing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12817703/android-full-layout-not-capturing)

In my Android application, I had listviews and set of buttons. I want to take screen shot of that layout contains all listviews and buttons, but am geting only visible part of listviews only.

How to capture invisible listview items in android?

Comment: repeat the same vague and unreadable question won't get your problem solved.

Comment: scroll it and then take screenshot :P

Answer (score 0):

> How to capture invisible listview items in android?

There are no "invisible listview items", by and large.

Let's say that you have a `ListView` that has space to show 10 rows, and your adapter returns 10000 from `getCount()`. Android does not create 10000 row `Views`. It creates 10 row `Views` (or perhaps a few more), and recycles them as the user scrolls. Hence, at the time you take your "screenshot", most of your rows simply do not exist in a visual form.

Comment: Ya, that's ok but am want all listview items to take screenshot..if listviews contains 100items i want to take all items as capture in android..

Comment: @user74: Most likely, you would need to manually inflate each of the rows yourself, take an image of each, and stitch the results together to pretend they are all in a `ListView`.